# TypeORM, createQueryBuilder with CAST and AS, any option?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using TypeORM with Nestjs, and after checking [docs about TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/getting-values-using-querybuilder) and [github repo](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/235#issuecomment-290813758), can't find any example or answer of my problem.

I am having the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(CAST("amountA" AS DECIMAL)) OVER (ORDER BY CAST("priceA" AS DECIMAL) ASC, id) AS quantity_amount
    FROM public."order"
    WHERE item_a_id= 1
    AND item_b_id = 4
    AND CAST("priceA" AS DECIMAL) <= CAST('92481' AS DECIMAL)
    ORDER BY "priceA" ASC
) AS c
WHERE c.quantity_amount <= CAST('100000' AS DECIMAL);
```

As you may see, it converts some `varchar` fields from string to decimanls because I am dealing with `BigNumber` and I am not using `decimals` in Entity.

And also I have this part, with `AS c` which is used later. So my question is:

> *Can I use `createQueryBuilder` of TypeORM and how exactly I should pass such string as: `AND CAST("priceA" AS DECIMAL) <= CAST('92481' AS DECIMAL)` and `AS c` and field `quantity_amount` from my subQuery?*

Is there any other options? Because as for now, I am dealing with plain `SQL` and `query` method instead of `createQueryBuilder`.

Comment: I have a similar problem... Using queryBuilder, I have:

    `.select([\`CONVERT(year, UNSIGNED) as year\`])`

But the response is still formatted as a string
    `year: '2010'`